# Getting physical screen height in pixels on Android

Tags: android, height, screen, statusbar

I've looked over many similar questions here but I'm still unable to get the complete height (minus status bar and nav bar) in pixels.

My primary devices are a Nexus 10 in portrait mode (1600 x 2560) and a handset with a resolution of 720x1280 and my app is running in 'Immersive mode' (sticky).

Basically, If I simply do this:

```
metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
width = metrics.widthPixels;
height = metrics.heightPixels+navigationBarHeight;
```

On the Nexus 10 tablet it returns 2464 - not the full height - there is a 'soft' naviation bar at the bottom of the screen when the user swipes up.
On the phone, it returns 1280 - the correct full height - the phone doesn't display a navigation bar - it has physical buttons for this, so both of these make sense.

Now, if I do this first:

```
int navigationBarHeight = 0;

    int resource = getResources().getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resource > 0) {
        navigationBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resource);
    }
```

On the Nexus 10, this returns 96.  I simply add the Nav bar height to the height obtained earlier like so:

```
width = metrics.widthPixels+navigationBarHeight;
```

On the Nexus 10 - we get 2560 and the app runs full-screen.  Perfect and makes sense.

However, the code above, also returns 96 on the phone.  I don't understand why this is - this phone doesn't have a soft nav bar so why is this not returning 0?
My code adds this together and I get 1376, which is clearly not correct (should be 1280)

Also, oddly, even though the 'status bar' returns 49, this isn't subtracted from the height returned by DisplayMetrics - I don't understand why.

I should also note that I need a solution that will work on Gingerbread.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this information?

Comment: My app is an OpenGL(ES 2.0)  Game and I'm using this information to correctly scale my objects across various devices - at run-time the app should query the current devices' screen, get it's pixel dimensions and then use that to scale against my 'base' (which is the ratio of the screen of the primary device on which the app is being developed on).